# Why does my recursive function, that involves async calls in a loop, not return to the caller function to continue a loop?

Tags: node.js, recursion

This is an attempt by me to do a static analysis of program with many files, all having import statements referencing other files in the program, to find cyclic references. The dependenciesCollection is a map of [key, value] entries with file names as keys and an array of their dependency files as the values. This code is running in node.js v12, and I need the async/await to give node the chance for garbage collection, else it bombs out with stack overflow. I can't get the function to return back up the stack to return to the calling function and continue the for loop where it was called from. What am I doing wrong?

```
let cyclicReferences = [] // a global array of pathToken arrays
const parseCollection = async (currentPathTokens, fileName, dependenciesCollection, targetFile, report) => {
  // currentPathTokens has entries for the sequence of entries leading to this file
  let dependencies = dependenciesCollection.item(fileName) // get array of dependent file names to investigate
  // Some testing code here omitted for brevity
  for (let index = 0; index < dependencies.length; index++) {
    let nextFile = dependencies[index]
    currentPathTokens.push(nextFile) //traveled path so far
    await parseCollection(currentPathTokens, nextFile, dependenciesCollection, targetFile, report)
    // I want the called recursive function to return to continue the for loop here, but it does not.
    currentPathTokens.pop() // shorten the path to dependency's parent node
  }
  // At end of this for loop, return to the caller to continue the loop there.
  // Never happens! Always goes back to the very first caller, never an intermediate one.
}
```

Comment: Do you think you can rewrite this as something we can run in an embed?

Comment: And why is this an async function? It looks like the only async part of it, is the recursive function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing my approach from using a recursive solution to using a Breadth-First-Search (BFS) solution of a tree graph. My main data source is a map object with keyed value arrays. Each of the 48 keys is a name of a file in my project. Each key's value is an array of names of the dependency files imported. So this map can be considered a representation of a tree data structure where each key is a node and each value array is a list of the child nodes. Each key is either treated as a root node or as a child node under another root. See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/all-you-need-to-know-about-tree-data-structures-bceacb85490c/ for a discussion about working with binary trees. My tree is not a binary tree, as most of the nodes have over two children. But the freecodecamp's discussion about implementing a BFS algorithm gives the information needed to work with my tree. The queue data structure is an array and can accommodate more than two child nodes added for each level. I loop through the main map object to pick each key as a root node and then process it level by level to inspect each child node. If I find a child node with the name of the root node, then I've found a cyclic reference that needs to be fixed.

```
    let theQueue = []
    let cyclicReferencesCollection = new Collection()
    let targetFile // a reference to this file from a dependent is a cyclic reference
    dependenciesCollection.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
      targetFile = fileName // any reference back to here is cyclic
      let theNodeObject = { level: 0, name: `${fileName}`, path: [`${fileName}`] }
      theQueue.length = 0 // reset
      theQueue.push(theNodeObject)
      let filesQueued = [] // a list of child nodes inspected
      /*********start looping over levels from this tree root************* */
      while (theQueue.length > 0) {
        let theNodeObject = theQueue.splice(0, 1)[0] // get next node object from queue
        let thisLevel = theNodeObject.level + 1
        let thisFile = theNodeObject.name
        let currentPath = theNodeObject.path // current path array
        if (theQueue.length > 0 && targetFile === thisFile) {
          // when the queue is empty, the targetFile will equal thisFile
          cyclicReferencesCollection.add([...currentPath], targetFile)
          break // we found a cyclic reference, start the next root
        }
        let dependencies = dependenciesCollection.item(thisFile)
        // these are the child nodes
        if (dependencies) {
          dependencies.forEach((fileName) => {
            if (!filesQueued.includes(fileName)) {
              // don't queue child nodes already inspected
              filesQueued.push(fileName) // save name to prevent dup testing
              let theNodeObject = { level: thisLevel, name: `${fileName}`, path: [...currentPath, `${fileName}`] }
              theQueue.push(theNodeObject)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
```